# What kind of Java List should I use to maintain a set of data

Tags: java

I have a dataset, and I'm not sure which type of List or Map to use in Java.
Following is a sample dataset.
There are **2 columns**, Users and Errors.

**A user can be repeated**. Errors are random and there won't be any duplicates.

**Users Errors**

User A  Error 1

User B  Error 2

User A  Error 3

User C  Error 4

and I should be able to use the list to **get all** **errors per user** at the end.

I tried a hashmap, but it only retrieves the last entry for user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `HashMap<String, Set<String>>` where key is `user` and value is `set of errors`. use `Set` to avoid duplicate errors for any user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap<User,List<Error>` (not sure if there are `User` and `Error` classes or if they are represented by Strings or some numeric type, but you get the idea).

This will make it easy to obtain the `List` of all errors for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map of String to List. 
Depending on java version you might need to do manual checks if given key exists (in such case add the error) or doesn't (create list and add a single error)